# Trouble understanding whence a copy constructor came

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

I have the following small code:

```
template <typename T>
class V
{
    public:
        T x;

    explicit V(T & _x)
    :x(_x){}

};

int main()
{
    V<float> b(1.0f); // fails
    return 0;
}
```

And it happens to fail. The message returned by g++ 4.4.5 is:

> `g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.d" -o"main.o" "../main.cpp"`
>   `../main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:`
>   `../main.cpp:19: error: no matching function for call to ‘V<float>::V(float)’`
>   `../main.cpp:10: note: candidates are: V<T>::V(T&) [with T = float]`
>   `../main.cpp:6: note:  V<float>::V(const V<float>&)`

The thing is... whence the second constructor came? I really have no clue...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Other answers discuss why you're getting a compile-time failure (which is what most questions are about when such failures are the most prominent part of the question).  However. regarding your explicit question, "whence the second constructor came?":

12.8/4 "Copying class objects" of standard says:

> If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy constructor, one is declared implicitly.

If you'd like to avoid the implicit copy-ctor from being used, one of a few 'non-copyable' idioms can be used (such as `boost::noncopyable`): http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Non-copyable_Mixin

Comment: This. The compiler does it for you. Default constructor and a copy constructor are supplied.

Comment: Ooh, I should have seen that.... Thanks you very much! What distracted me is the fact that the copy constructor is not applicable at all for the expression in which I get the failure, since there is no way to obtain a V object from the float literal (the V(float&) constructor is explicit).

Comment: @user this is why GCC says "candidate". Candidates are all constructors, but "viable candidates" are only the ones that could actually accept the argument.

Answer (score 4):

Compiler has supplied a copy constructor and assignment operator to your class. It is trying to match that copy constructor with your statement in `main`. The problem with this code is that in the constructor of class `V` you are taking the parameter as a non-const reference. When you do `V<float> b(1.0f)`, compiler will create an unnamed temporary variable of type `float` for the value `1.0f`. However, this unnamed temporary can not be bound to a non-const reference, it can be bound only to a const reference. Hence you need to change the constructor signature to `explicit V(const T & _x)`.